# A clean transition between 2 different bevels

Tags: modeling, bevel

I have a problem that I can't get a clean transition between two different bevels.
The first picture shows how the rounding must be from the car body itself. Now I have to make a clean transition to the rounding of the front. Can someone help me or explain how I can best proceed?

[image: Bevel 1]

[image: Bevel 2]

[image: Real Image]